# Design a GUI in IntelliJ placing the components freely, as in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, netbeans, jframe

In Netbeans you can freely design an interface or form, just as you design the components or where you place them in the design, as it appears when you give it to run.

On the other hand, in IntelliJ you make the components and put them in a place, you give it to run and it does not come out as is, there was a time where if it can do it I think but I do not remember and now it does not come out.

Is it possible in IntelliJ to design a graphical user interface by placing the components freely, as in Netbeans?

Comment: Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You should NOT attempt to manually position components at some random position on the screen. Learn how to manually create your forms and then you are not dependent on the tool you are using. You won't be able to maintain the code if you ever move to a different tool.

Answer (score 2):

Yes IntelliJ IDEA has a GUI Designer built in. Just open a form file and you can use the designer. Documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gui-designer-basics.html

Here are some screenshots outlining creating a form file and the designer itself.

[image: creating form]

[image: gui desinger]